# Why would the same jsf code only fail on one environment if all environments are the same?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tomcat7

Scenario:

Same code in Local, Demonstration, Pre-Production and Production environments,
Same application server Tomcat version 7.0.92 version in Local, Demonstration, Pre-Production and Production environments
Same JVM version in each environment
Same application server configuration (minus port # 8081 in pre-production, 8080 in production) and jvmRoute assigned in Production for load balancing.

Can duplicate this on the production server locally which means at that point I am not going through the http server/balancer.

But this code below acts differently in Production than it does in Local, Demonstration, and Pre-Production.  You could say it "works" in all environments EXCEPT production...

Works meaning the Upload button on the fileUploadDialog is disabled on initial page load due to no upload type being selected (i.e. uploadType = null). Once an upload type is selected, the upload button is not disabled anymore and allows client to upload a document.  If it is selected again as "Please Select One..." uploadType is null again and Upload button is disabled.  Pretty straight forward.

These cases DO NOT happen in production and the Upload button is always enabled allowing the client to submit a incomplete document to the database and therefore causing a 500 error in subsequent operations.

Some more information.  This is buried in a single form with THOUSANDS or lines of code above it. It is a "GOD" view.

```
                    <p:dialog id="uploadSupportingDocsDlg"
                          header="File Upload"
                          modal="true"
                          widgetVar="uploadSupportingDocsDlg"
                          closable="true"
                          resizable="true"
                          draggable="true" >
                    <center>
                        <p:message for="uploadType" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="uploadType"
                                         style="vertical-align: middle;"
                                         value="#{backingBean.uploadType}"
                                         rendered="#{backingBean.application.type eq 'TYPE1'
                                                     or backingBean.application.type eq 'TYPE2'
                                                     or backingBean.application.type eq 'TYPE3' }"
                                         appendTo="@this">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select One..." itemValue="#{null}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.requiredDocsDropdownList}" var="upload" itemLabel="#{upload.doctype}" itemValue="#{upload.doctype}" />
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="@widgetVar(supportingFileUploadDialog)" process="uploadType"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </center>
                    <center>
                        <p:fileUpload style="width: 750px;"
                                      mode="advanced"
                                      widgetVar="supportingFileUploadDialog"
                                      fileLimit="1"
                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|PDF|jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG|png|PNG)$/"
                                      sizeLimit="4000000000"
                                      invalidSizeMessage="File must be 4GB or less"
                                      invalidFileMessage="Invalid file type: File must be in PDF, JPG, or PNG format"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{backingBean.uploadAdditionalDocument}"
                                      onstart="PF('uploadDlg').show();"
                                      oncomplete="PF('uploadDlg').hide();"
                                      update="@form, @this"  
                                      disabled="#{backingBean.uploadType eq null}">
                        </p:fileUpload>
                    </center>
                </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Tomcat (7) and java-ee (6) are a contradiction in terms and both are rather old!!!!_. And with using thesse as tags you also explicitly state it works other tomcat  or java-ee versions

Comment: Any insight on the cause @Kukeltje?

Comment: Sure... Complete **chain** of systems **not** identical (including e.g. reverse proxy/loadbalancer in there or related, you even mentioned that).

Comment: Try `#{empty backingBean.uploadType}` instead. If that works, Google "Empty string madness".

Comment: I updated the question to include information you said was missing.  I can duplicate on the production server locally while behind the http server/load balancer. @Kukeltje

Comment: Thank you @BalusC I will try that and see.

Comment: @BalusC: That woud only be logical if the environments differ more than OP mentiones wouldn't it? E.g. different JSF/EL version etc.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Agreed but so far symptoms indicate that production environment _actually_ differs.

Comment: All of tomcat libs are the same between servers.  Same size, same date stamps. Both servers are from the same vm image that had tomcat setup prior.

Comment: @Kukeltje did you try cleaning the browsers cache? could be a browser version problem, which browsers are you using

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast ?????? Why shoud **_I_** clear the browser cache? It is not my problem....

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue on the same version of browser.  If I hit this code with the same browser side by side, one side going to Pre-Production and the other to Production, I can see the issue only happening in the Production side window.  I have compared both tomcat installations, both application code between the two and can find no difference besides the port # and the jvmRoute in tomcat’s server.xml mentioned in the question body.  I am baffled.

Comment: @Kukeltje Lmao not you dude, I just ment to call your attention if you think that could be cause too xD

Comment: @Anden So atleast you can discard now all those factors... what else do they need to run the whole application? websockets? microservices? configuration files? check everything

Comment: And you debugged why up;oadType is not null?

Comment: Yes, when I debugged the method that checks for uploadType to be null, it skipped that block and continued execution passed the null check.